# Eth going down randomly state "unmanaged" on Centos

Tags: centos, networkmanager, ethernet

Centos 7.9.2009 (Core) NetworkManager is driving me mad- ethernet going down randomly. First it was going down in couple of minutes. After I kept trying tweaks from forums, I have achieved almost 2 weeks without this annoying error. This is just basic installation with web server and mysql, no gui etc.
Wireless connection does not seem to have these issues but I'd like to use ethernet.
What can I do to keep wired connection stable?
I don't care if I use NetworkManager, netplan or anything else, I just need the ethernet working stable:)

Now after reboot, it looks ok again.

```
DEVICE      TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------
enp2s0      ethernet  connected  enp2s0
```

```
# Configuration file for NetworkManager.
#
# See "man 5 NetworkManager.conf" for details.
#
# The directories /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/ and /var/run/NetworkManager/conf.d/
# can contain additional configuration snippets installed by packages. These files are
# read before NetworkManager.conf and have thus lowest priority.
# The directory /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/ can contain additional configuration
# snippets. Those snippets are merged last and overwrite the settings from this main
# file.
#
# The files within one conf.d/ directory are read in asciibetical order.
#
# If /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/ contains a file with the same name as
# /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/, the latter file is shadowed and thus ignored.
# Hence, to disable loading a file from /usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/ you can
# put an empty file to /etc with the same name. The same applies with respect
# to the directory /var/run/NetworkManager/conf.d where files in /var/run shadow
# /usr/lib and are themselves shadowed by files under /etc.
#
# If two files define the same key, the one that is read afterwards will overwrite
# the previous one.

[main]
#plugins=ifcfg-rh,ibft,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

[logging]
# When debugging NetworkManager, enabling debug logging is of great help.
#
# Logfiles contain no passwords and little sensitive information. But please
# check before posting the file online. You can also personally hand over the
# logfile to a NM developer to treat it confidential. Meet us on #nm on freenode.
# Please post full logfiles except minimal modifications of private data.
#
# You can also change the log-level at runtime via
#   $ nmcli general logging level TRACE domains ALL
# However, usually it's cleaner to enable debug logging
# in the configuration and restart NetworkManager so that
# debug logging is enabled from the start.
#
# You will find the logfiles in syslog, for example via
#   $ journalctl -u NetworkManager
#
# Note that debug logging of NetworkManager can be quite verbose. Some messages
# might be rate-limited by the logging daemon (see RateLimitIntervalSec, RateLimitBurst
# in man journald.conf).
#
#level=TRACE
#domains=ALL
```

Thanks

Edit: went log hunting, seems like it is tired or something

```
Jan  4 09:57:13 localhost kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
Jan  4 09:57:13 localhost kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
Jan  4 09:57:13 localhost kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
Jan  4 09:57:13 localhost kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
Jan  4 09:57:13 localhost kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
Jan  4 09:57:13 localhost kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: BAR 6: [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x2] has bogus alignment
Jan  4 09:57:13 localhost systemd-logind: Suspending...
Jan  4 09:57:13 localhost NetworkManager[2639]: <info>  [1672822633.9215] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Jan  4 09:57:13 localhost NetworkManager[2639]: <info>  [1672822633.9408] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Jan  4 09:57:13 localhost NetworkManager[2639]: <info>  [1672822633.9462] device (enp2s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan  4 09:57:14 localhost NetworkManager[2639]: <info>  [1672822634.0095] device (enp2s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan  4 09:57:14 localhost dbus[679]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Jan  4 09:57:14 localhost NetworkManager[2639]: <info>  [1672822634.0411] dhcp4 (enp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 2753
Jan  4 09:57:14 localhost NetworkManager[2639]: <info>  [1672822634.0411] dhcp4 (enp2s0): state changed bound -> done
Jan  4 09:57:14 localhost avahi-daemon[703]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::1812:4c50:9a40:bf5a on enp2s0.
Jan  4 09:57:14 localhost avahi-daemon[703]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.51.108 on enp2s0.
Jan  4 09:57:14 localhost avahi-daemon[703]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp2s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.51.108.
Jan  4 09:57:14 localhost avahi-daemon[703]: Interface enp2s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jan  4 09:57:14 localhost systemd: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jan  4 09:57:14 localhost dnsmasq[1656]: no servers found in /etc/resolv.conf, will retry
Jan  4 09:57:14 localhost NetworkManager[2639]: <info>  [1672822634.1763] device (enp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan  4 09:57:14 localhost systemd-logind: Failed to send delayed message: Unit is masked.
Jan  4 09:57:14 localhost systemd-logind: Suspending...
Jan  4 09:57:14 localhost systemd-logind: Failed to execute operation: Unit is masked.
Jan  4 09:57:14 localhost systemd-logind: Suspending...
Jan  4 09:57:14 localhost systemd-logind: Failed to execute operation: Unit is masked.
Jan  4 09:57:14 localhost systemd-logind: Suspending...
Jan  4 09:57:14 localhost systemd-logind: Failed to execute operation: Unit is masked.
Jan  4 09:57:14 localhost systemd-logind: Suspending...
```

Comment: What does the system log say when eth goes down? What does it take to bring is up again?

Comment: Either reboot or systemctl restart NetworkManager brings connection back. Good point with the logs - started huntnig and foud something.. seems like it would like to go to sleep or something- added log details in the OP.